# How to connect azure storage account using azure sdk for .net API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cloud-services

Is it possible to list out the cloud services for azure storage account with out using certification thumbprint . And also get the deployment ID for particular cloud service?

I have connected storage account(based on account key and account name) using azure storage client library and list out the tables and containers. My question is, displays the cloud services for particular storage account with out using certification.
Note: I saw rest api to list out the storage account and services using subscription id with certification.

I am waiting your response.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to list out the cloud services for azure storage
>   account with out using certification thumbprint . And also get the
>   deployment ID for particular cloud service?

To achieve this, you would need to use [`Azure Service Management API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx) and API calls need to be authenticated. Using X509 Certificate is one of them (which you don't want to use). Other way to achieve this would be to use Azure Active Directory. You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx#bk_ad however authenticating API requests using Azure AD is more complicated than using a certificate IMHO.

Comment: Thank you. Any Azure storage/client libray to get the deployment ID for particular storage account ?

Comment: AFAIK, none without using Service Management API. Assuming you're using separate storage accounts for each of your cloud service, you could query one of the diagnostics tables based on date/time range and get the deployment id from that table.

Comment: I saw account based authentication. Can we list out the cloud services using account based authentication ? code snippet for account based authentication to list the tables or blobs?

Comment: What do you mean by account based authentication?

Comment: refer this link [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531793.aspx)  difference between account based authentication and certificate based.  Construct the restapi with authenticated account key and date time

Comment: Did you even read my answer? Azure AD based authentication is another way of achieving this (which is your account based authentication). Please explain why you don't want to go with certificate based authentication (which BTW is quite straight forward) and want to use account based authentication (which is more complicated to implement IMHO)?